# Installing QGIS on Mac OS?

Tags: qgis, installation

I am having difficulty installing QGIS on my Mac OS X 10.7.5 (Lion). I understand that QGIS requires GDAL Complete 1.10 framework package and Matplotlib Python module. I installed GDAL (which includes PROJ, UnixImageIO, GEOS and SQLite3) and then I installed NumPy.

When I try to install QGIS, a message pops up saying that:

> QGIS requires the Matplotlib python module

I thought I took care of that by installing NumPy.

Does anyone have any advice to share?

Comment: use http://www.kyngchaos.com/software/python matplotlib 1.3.0-3 [71.8 MiB] (Snow Leopard, Lion, & Mt Lion)